# Gnu AS equivalent of ORG in NASM

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

What would be the equivalent directive in GAS for the ORG (origin) directive in NASM?

EDIT: A warning to all: `.org` is not the origin directive, it seems to instead pad the assembled file with `00` up to the specified address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know beans about NASM, but I have the impression that it includes functionality that, in GNU toolchain land, is considered the linker's responsibility, not the assembler's.

You may need to mark up your assembly sources with custom [`.section`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html#Section) directives and then write a [linker script](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts) to put each section at the desired address.

Comment: Nasm's `org` applies only in "-f bin" output format, which (G)as won't do... but ld will. `ld -oformat binary -Ttext=0x7C00 -o myfile.bin myfile.o` or something...

Comment: @frankKotler that's what I'm currently doing, unfortunately this leaves the entire code based at `0x7c00`. What if part of `.text` gets relocated to a different address (perhaps for an interrupt handler?)

Comment: @Zack sorry for the bluntness of my early comment, I had just wasted a lot of time under the same assumption. In retrospect it looks like I'm being rude and immature, sorry.

Comment: @Hawken Don't worry about it; like I said, I don't know beans about NASM.  (In GNU toolchain land, though, the answer to "what if part of `.text` [needs to be] relocated to a different address" is definitely "you need a linker script".  And you're going to have to put the interrupt handler in a special section.)

Comment: @Zack could you write a second answer with only the second portion of this answer? I can't mark this as the answer since it contains `.org` and I don't want to mislead anyone, and since I already downvoted it I can't upvote it and give you credit. < gah, this is a mess! ;)

Comment: @Hawken I've revised my answer.  You should be able to retract your downvote by clicking on the down arrow again, if you want.